# mysql_num_rows() Error

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, rows, mysql-num-rows

```
<?php
$id=$_GET['id'];
$username="xxx";
$password="xxx";
$database="xxx";
$host="xxx";
mysql_connect($host,$username,$password);
$con = mysql_connect("$host","$username","$password");

$id=$_POST['ID'];
$query="SELECT * FROM vbots WHERE ID=$id";
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM vbots");
$num=mysql_query($result,$con) or die("Error: ". mysql_error(). " with query ". $query);
mysql_close();
```

I keep getting

> Error: Query was empty with query
>   SELECT * FROM vbots WHERE ID=1"

How can i fix that?
I get it from mysql_num_rows() , wrote `die("Error: ". mysql_error(). " with query ". $query);` for more info .

Thank you !

Comment: `$num=mysql_query` is that meant to be `$num=mysql_num_rows` ?

Comment: are you sure that's the code running?

Comment: Why do you create the $query variable and not use it? Also you don't even use the mysql_num_rows() function in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mixed something up with your query.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM vbots");
$num=mysql_query($result,$con); //! $result is already a result from a query. 
//You can't 'query a result'…
```

So this should just work:

```
$id=$_GET['id'];
$username="xxx";
$password="xxx";
$database="xxx";
$host="xxx";
$con = mysql_connect($host,$username,$password);
if (!mysql_select_db($database))
    die("Can't select database");

$id=$_POST['ID'];
$query="SELECT * FROM vbots WHERE ID=$id";
$result = mysql_query($query);
echo mysql_num_rows($result);
mysql_close();
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code should be

```
$id=$_POST['ID'];
$query="SELECT * FROM vbots WHERE ID=$id";
$result = mysql_query($query, $con) or die("Error: ". mysql_error(). " with query ". $query);
$num=mysql_num_rows($result);
mysql_close();
```

You are using

```
$num=mysql_query($result,$con)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need check the query result at first.

```
if (!$result) {
    //handling empty set or error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to select your database:

```
if (!mysql_select_db($database))
    die("Can't select database");
```